# Design question: usage of static methods inside other methods in python class

Tags: python, static-methods

I would like to ask about usage of static methods inside other methods in python class. I don't know where should i post it, but meta.stackexchange recommended to post it here.

What i want to do is to build `StringProcessor` class, which should preprocess a string.
I want to start with basic functionality(like deletion of bad characters, strip etc.) but later the plan is to extend basic functionality.

First variant of the class:

```
import re


class StringProcessor:
    """
    This class is responsible for the string preprocessing.
    """
    def __init__(self,bad_chars = None):
        self.bad_chars = bad_chars
            

    def link_processor(self,string):
        #preprocessing of the link
        return string


    def name_surname_processor(self,string):
        #manipulation with names and surnames

        return string

    def delete_bad_characters(self,string):
        if self.bad_chars is not None:
            return string.translate(self.bad_chars)
        return string
        

    def standard_processor(self,string):
        string = self.delete_bad_characters(string)
        string = self.link_processor(string)
        string = string.strip()
        string = string.lower()

        return string
```

So here I am stick to the instance methods.

Here is the second variant of the class:

```
class StringProcessor:
    """
    This class is responsible for the string preprocessing.
    """
    def __init__(self,bad_chars = None):
        self.bad_chars = bad_chars
            
    @staticmethod
    def link_processor(string):
        #preprocessing of the link
        return string

    @staticmethod
    def name_surname_processor(string):
        #preprocessing of the name and surname
        return string

        return string

    def delete_bad_characters(self,string):
        if self.bad_chars is not None:
            return string.translate(self.bad_chars)
        return string
        
    def standard_processor(self,string):
        string = self.delete_bad_characters(string)
        string = self.link_processor(string)
        string = string.strip()
        string = string.lower()

        return string
```

The idea is, that `standard_processor()` is a main method, which uses other helper methods(like `link_processor`) for the string preprocessing. My question is: in this case is it better to use @`staticmethod` for the helper methods of it's better to stick with regular instance methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use @staticmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508248/why-do-we-use-staticmethod), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667667/how-to-use-static-helper-method-in-a-class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855237/python-should-i-put-my-helper-functions-inside-or-outside-the-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of preference.   Adding static methods to a class simply adds that function to the class's namespace.  It does have the benefit of being able to call the static method without having instantiated the class.  I.e.:

```py
class StringProcessor:
    """
    This class is responsible for the string preprocessing.
    """
    def __init__(self,bad_chars = None):
        self.bad_chars = bad_chars
            
    @staticmethod
    def drop_newlines(string):
        return re.sub(r'[\n\r]', '', string)


# not-instantiated
StringProcessor.drop_newlines('hello\nworld')
# returns:
'helloworld'
```

My preference is to not use static methods, and instead keep them as functions that are called within the class.

```py
def drop_newlines(string):
    return re.sub(r'[\n\r]', '', string)

def reduce_white_space(string):
    return re.sub(r'[\t ]+', ' ', string)

class StringProcessor:
    """
    This class is responsible for the string preprocessing.
    """
    def __init__(self,bad_chars = None):
        self.bad_chars = bad_chars
            
    def clean_whitespace(self, string):
        out = drop_newlines(string)
        out = reduce_white_space(out)
        return out
```

However, as I was writing this, I noticed that we are calling `re.sub`.  This is fine if it is used occasionally, but you can speed it up by compiling the regular expression first, and then calling `.sub`.  But where to store the compiled regexes?  Well, that is what attributes in classes are for!

So here is how I would probably write it:

```py
class StringProcessor:
    """
    This class is responsible for the string preprocessing.
    """
    REGEX_NEWLINE = re.compile(r'[\n\r]')
    REGEX_WHITESPACE = re.compile(r'[\t ]+')

    def __init__(self,bad_chars = None):
        self.bad_chars = bad_chars

    def drop_newlines(self, string):
        return self.REGEX_NEWLINE.sub('', string)

    def reduce_white_space(self, string):
        return self.REGEX_WHITESPACE.sub(' ', string)
            
    def clean_whitespace(self, string):
        out = self.drop_newlines(string)
        out = self.reduce_white_space(out)
        return out
```

But again, just my opinion.